# Python Filter output in if loop?

Tags: python, strip

I got the following code:

```
def gps():
    print("\t\tGPS information:")
    for tag in tags.keys():
        if 'GPS' in tag:
            print "%s: , %s" % (tag, tags[tag])
```

When I run this my output looks like:

```
GPS GPSLatitudeRef: , S
GPS GPSLatitude: , [33, 51, 2191/100]
GPS GPSLongitude: , [151, 13, 1173/100]
GPS GPSVersionID: , [0, 0, 2, 2]
```

How can I filter the text so it removes GPS?
I did try it with spitline but cant get it to work in the if loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To replace all 'GPS' just replace it with empty string,

```
if 'GPS' in tag:
    print "%s: , %s" % (tag.replace('GPS', ''), tags[tag])
```

Or, just the first occurrence with,

```
if 'GPS' in tag:
    print "%s: , %s" % (tag.replace('GPS', '', 1), tags[tag])
```

Specifying how many occurrences to replace (1 in this case). Or, like zondo specified,

```
tag.lstrip('GPS')
```

**Update**

To remove the space at the beginning you can use the lstrip method

```
tag.replace('GPS', '').lstrip()
```

Comment: Or `tag.lstrip("GPS")`

Comment: Thanks! Is there away to remove the new space in the output? There is a empty space before LatitudeRef now (and the rest)

Comment: @zondo and @joey: More specifically, we want `tag.lstrip("GPS ")`, including the space, for two reasons: A) `"GPS"` (no space at end) will leave a leading space, and B) `"GPS "` will ensure that, if a tag comes in as *just* "GPSLatitudeRef", it will *not* remove that.

Comment: @BHustus: Frankly, you're wrong.  `tag.lstrip("GPS").lstrip()` would do it, but `tag.lstrip("GPS ")` will turn `"GPS GPSTHIS"` into `"THIS"`.  We want to remove only the first occurrence of `"GPS"`.

Comment: @zondo : Oh. I guess I'd misunderstood the idea behind `lstrip` - but the space-end version *will* work as intended for the original answer.

Comment: Thanks zondo for the tip. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If your sample output is the right representation of what your output looks like.

```
if 'GPS' in tag:
    print "%s: , %s" % (tag.split(' ')[1], tags[tag])
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's not most convenient solution in Python, but you can use also use regular expression for more complicated replacements:

```
import re

for tag in tags.keys():
    print "%s: %s" % (re.sub(r'^.*?GPS', '', tag), tags[tag])
```

(to delete first GPS occurence). If you want to delete all **from the beginning to 'GPS' (including GPS)**, just type:

```
print "%s: %s" % (re.sub(r'^.*GPS', '', tag), tags[tag])
```

(remove '?' question mark). However, for string like:

```
"GPS SomeStringGPS"
```

You'll get empty string in result, so be careful.

EDITED: Added second case.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer! But It only removes the first GPS

Comment: Sorry, I thought about one thing and wrote another. I edited with some usage example that might be little tricky. Regular expressions are powerful tool, yet one should be very careful using them.